# No Sound For Only One User v16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a new computer.  The sound worked fine for all users right after the installation but suddenly, the sound indicator was set to mute and I was unable to adjust the sound (the sound still plays though!!).

If I login as a different user (or even to guest session), the sound and sound indicator both work flawlessly.  I tried to reinstall ALSA and pulseaudio but nothing changed.  The weirdest part is that sound comes out of the speakers.

I don't think its a hardware detection failure because sound is coming out of the speakers, I have no idea what to try next - thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: is the sound coming from the speakers related to those actions the current user takes? what I am aiming at: if you switch users without signing the first user off, any audio application that still runs may keep the audio controls and output to himself/herself. the second user after being logged in might still hear for example the musik of user one. Though I must admit, I never tried this myself, I would not be surprised if the audio controls were locked as well.

Comment: **Please note** that messed up permissions in our HOME is entirely unrelated to pulseaudio or sound setup.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/201780/how-do-i-debug-issues-with-pulse-audio for a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. The problem was already answered by [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342699/no-sound-devices-displayed-in-settings-but-speakers-work-and-startup-noise-play):

I had to change permission for my home directory:

`sudo chown -R <username> /home/<username>`

Comment: You are changed the ownership of your home directory by command 'chown'.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. Fixed it by killing pulseaudio and deleting its config folder:

```
killall pulseaudio && mv ~/.config/pulse/ /tmp/deleted_pulse_config
```

Comment: If someone updated his Ubuntu and had the issue this is the answer

Comment: This was the solution for me after I restored my Home area with rsync.
Removing the above directory, then logging out and back in again.